# Spring Cloud's @RefreshScope causes controller mapping collision with itself

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at [this link](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/13/configuring-it-all-out-or-12-factor-app-style-configuration-with-spring) to test out Spring Cloud, but whenever I wire up my controller with `@RefreshScope` I get an error that the `RequestMapping` has already been taken. If I drop `@RefreshScope` things work great and I see the value from the config-server.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Code:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebCloudPoc {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(WebCloudPoc.class, args);
    }


    @RestController
    @RefreshScope
    public static class ProjectNameRestController {

        @Value("${configuration.projectName}")
        private String projectName;

        @RequestMapping("/project-name")
        public String projectName() {
            return this.projectName;
        }
    }
}
```

The log output is below:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55585', transport: 'socket'
2015-04-16 12:50:26.227  INFO 9744 --- [           main] com.example.web.WebCloudPoc               : Starting WebCloudPoc on MacBook-Pro with PID 9744 (/Users/dave/workspace/7oaks/example/modules/example-web/target/classes started by dave in /Users/dave/workspace/7oaks/example)
2015-04-16 12:50:26.259  INFO 9744 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4d154ccd: startup date [Thu Apr 16 12:50:26 MDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-04-16 12:50:26.608  INFO 9744 --- [           main] com.example.web.WebCloudPoc               : Started WebCloudPoc in 0.65 seconds (JVM running for 1.101)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.1.RELEASE)

2015-04-16 12:50:26.908  INFO 9744 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource [name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource [name='applicationConfig: [file:/Users/dave/workspace/7oaks/example/modules/sysops/src/main/resources/test/demo.app.properties]']]]
2015-04-16 12:50:26.919  INFO 9744 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6a1d204a: startup date [Thu Apr 16 12:50:26 MDT 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4d154ccd
2015-04-16 12:50:27.409  INFO 9744 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2015-04-16 12:50:27.471  INFO 9744 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'infoEndpoint': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=infoEndpoint; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointAutoConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$InfoEndpointRebinderConfiguration; factoryMethodName=infoEndpoint; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration$InfoEndpointRebinderConfiguration.class]]
2015-04-16 12:50:27.556  INFO 9744 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=dd9ead28-6b26-31d0-803c-8df18aadded5
2015-04-16 12:50:27.576  INFO 9744 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$de7234f0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-04-16 12:50:27.818  INFO 9744 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2015-04-16 12:50:27.966  INFO 9744 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-04-16 12:50:27.967  INFO 9744 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
2015-04-16 12:50:28.033  INFO 9744 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-04-16 12:50:28.033  INFO 9744 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1114 ms
2015-04-16 12:50:28.323  INFO 9744 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-04-16 12:50:28.327  INFO 9744 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'metricFilter' to: [/*]
2015-04-16 12:50:28.327  INFO 9744 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-04-16 12:50:28.327  INFO 9744 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-04-16 12:50:28.327  INFO 9744 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2015-04-16 12:50:28.327  INFO 9744 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2015-04-16 12:50:28.531  INFO 9744 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6a1d204a: startup date [Thu Apr 16 12:50:26 MDT 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4d154ccd
2015-04-16 12:50:28.577  INFO 9744 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/project-name],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController.projectName()
2015-04-16 12:50:28.581  WARN 9744 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController' bean method 
public java.lang.String com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController.projectName()
to {[/project-name],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'webCloudPoc.ProjectNameRestController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController.projectName() mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at com.example.web.WebCloudPoc.main(WebCloudPoc.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController' bean method 
public java.lang.String com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController.projectName()
to {[/project-name],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'webCloudPoc.ProjectNameRestController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController.projectName() mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 15 common frames omitted

2015-04-16 12:50:28.583  INFO 9744 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2015-04-16 12:50:28.589  INFO 9744 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/Users/dave/workspace/7oaks/example/modules/example-web/target/classes/, file:/Users/dave/workspace/7oaks/example/modules/example-common/target/classes/, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.8/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.8.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.8/slf4j-api-1.7.8.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.8/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.8.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.8/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.8.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.14/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.15/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.15/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.15.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.15/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.15.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.15/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.15.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.4/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.4/jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.4/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-config-client/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-config-client-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-crypto-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/dave/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.1/logback-core-1.1.1.jar, file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%2014.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar]
2015-04-16 12:50:28.589  INFO 9744 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


2015-04-16 12:50:28.590 ERROR 9744 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController' bean method 
public java.lang.String com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController.projectName()
to {[/project-name],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'webCloudPoc.ProjectNameRestController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController.projectName() mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at com.example.web.WebCloudPoc.main(WebCloudPoc.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController' bean method 
public java.lang.String com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController.projectName()
to {[/project-name],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'webCloudPoc.ProjectNameRestController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController.projectName() mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 15 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController' bean method 
2015-04-16 12:50:28.591public java.lang.String com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController.projectName()
  INFO 9744to {[/project-name],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'webCloudPoc.ProjectNameRestController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController.projectName() mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
--- at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
[       Thread-1]   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
 s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4d154ccd: startup date [Thu Apr 16 12:50:26 MDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at com.example.web.WebCloudPoc.main(WebCloudPoc.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController' bean method 
public java.lang.String com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController.projectName()
to {[/project-name],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'webCloudPoc.ProjectNameRestController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.example.web.WebCloudPoc$ProjectNameRestController.projectName() mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 15 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55585', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Hey dave!  I've reproduced here https://github.com/spencergibb/communityanswers/tree/29683709-refresh-scope, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@David Welch,  I think it has to do with the way `@Configuration` classes (which `@SpringBootApplication` is) handle static inner classes.  I [moved](https://github.com/spencergibb/communityanswers/commit/84a0843eb3f9b93d6a952cc2b56f0208efee1e7b) the controller to a top level class and it all compiled and ran fine.

Comment: I think it says in the user guide that `@RefreshScope` doesn't work with `@Configuration` (there are tests to show it). Was that the problem?

Comment: `@RefreshScope` was on the Controller, defined as a class inside the configuration. That indeed was the problem, as the only solution was to move the controller to it's own file (even tho the example showed it as possible). The docs make it sound like tagging a `Configuration` is asking for trouble, but not that tagging a class in a configuration file would cause problems.